# How to subclass a widget

Tags: android

I was to subclass a button like this

```
import android.widget.Button;
public class MyButton extends Button {
    // ...
}
```

However, any widget I try to subclass results in a compiler error

> There is no default constructor available in [widget]

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: .... add a default constructor?

Comment: Add one in the import `android.widget.Button` source code?

Comment: Delete the default construct.

Comment: You mean override it, and call the parent constructor, got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're encountering is caused by the widgets having only constructors that take at least one parameter.

if you have a class `A` like this:

```
public class A {
    public A(String parameter) { // ... }
}
```

and you define a class `B` which extends `A`, then you **must** call the constructor of `A` in `B` like so:

```
public class B extends A {
    public B(){
        super("some string"); // you have to have this!
    }
}
```

In the case of your button, use this constructor

```
public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclasses in Java do not inherit the parent constructor, you will need to re-implement the 4 constructors belonging to Button. Just call the super constructor in each.